Crackling noise with external soundcard microphone input
I have a Terratec USB soundcard connected to my RPi4 running bookworm.
If I use
arecord -f cd -d 5 test.wav I get crackling noises with my microphone.
If I specify the device with arecord -f cd -d 5 -D plughw:CARD=HD,DEV=2 test.wav it works well.
arecord -l output:
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 1: HD [AUREON XFIRE8.0 HD], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HD [AUREON XFIRE8.0 HD], device 2: USB Audio [USB Audio #2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

arecord -L output:
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
default
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
sysdefault
    Default Audio Device
lavrate
    Rate Converter Plugin Using Libav/FFmpeg Library
samplerate
    Rate Converter Plugin Using Samplerate Library
speexrate
    Rate Converter Plugin Using Speex Resampler
jack
    JACK Audio Connection Kit
oss
    Open Sound System
pulse
    PulseAudio Sound Server
speex
    Plugin using Speex DSP (resample, agc, denoise, echo, dereverb)
upmix
    Plugin for channel upmix (4,6,8)
vdownmix
    Plugin for channel downmix (stereo) with a simple spacialization
sysdefault:CARD=vc4hdmi1
    Default Audio Device
usbstream:CARD=vc4hdmi1
    vc4-hdmi-1
    USB Stream Output
hw:CARD=HD,DEV=0
    AUREON XFIRE8.0 HD, USB Audio
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=HD,DEV=2
    AUREON XFIRE8.0 HD, USB Audio #2
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=HD,DEV=0
    AUREON XFIRE8.0 HD, USB Audio
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=HD,DEV=2
    AUREON XFIRE8.0 HD, USB Audio #2
    Hardware device with all software conversions
sysdefault:CARD=HD
    AUREON XFIRE8.0 HD, USB Audio #2
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=HD,DEV=0
    AUREON XFIRE8.0 HD, USB Audio
    Front output / input
dsnoop:CARD=HD,DEV=0
    AUREON XFIRE8.0 HD, USB Audio
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=HD,DEV=2
    AUREON XFIRE8.0 HD, USB Audio #2
    Direct sample snooping device
usbstream:CARD=HD
    AUREON XFIRE8.0 HD
    USB Stream Output

I tried setting the plughw as default in .asoundrc file
pcm.!default {
    type plug
    slave {
        pcm "plughw:HD,2"
    }
}

But this file gets deleted every boot.
Also changing it in pulseaudio config /etc/pulse/default.pa 
load-module module-alsa-source device=plughw:HD,2
set-default-source alsa_input.plughw_HD_2


did not make it better.
Any idea?

Since your .asoundrc file is getting deleted on every boot, try placing your configuration in /etc/asound.conf instead. This file should persist across reboots.
